# Regular expression for logical operators

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for the following pattern...for example:

```
osystems::win.2.vm#true AND osystems::win.2.vm#false AND (osystems::win.7.headless#false OR browsers::firefox.version#8)
```

I wish to parse this using a regular expression and end up with the following:

- osystems::win.2.vm#true
- AND
- osystems::win.2.vm#false
- AND
- (osystems::win.7.headless#false OR browsers::firefox.version#8)

Then I need to iterate through the list perform the necessary operations...starting from those in brackets in case there are any.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Split according to `AND`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Won't work for `(x AND y) OR z`

Comment: @tobias_k You're right, I didn't think OP might have this.

Comment: If you need to support an unlimited number of nested brackets, like `(a AND (b AND (c AND ((d AND e) AND f))))` then this is provably impossible.

Comment: @immibis you should write an answer on this.

Comment: I am happy with supporting one level say a AND b AND (c OR d) AND (e AND f)

Comment: You should implement a stack based on your AND strings and parenthesis precedence. As @immibis said it would be impossible with just a regex

Comment: but what if I have  a OR b AND (c OR d) OR (e AND f)

Answer (score 0):

In the following example two regex groups are defined. Maybe you could use this and extend the logic that if "browsers" is seen it belongs to the OS preceding.

```
    String in = "osystems::win.2.vm#true AND osystems::win.2.vm#false AND (osystems::win.7.headless#false OR browsers::firefox.version#8)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+::\\w+.\\d+.\\w+#\\w+)|(\\w+::\\w+.\\w+#\\d)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Output:

```
osystems::win.2.vm#true
osystems::win.2.vm#false
osystems::win.7.headless#false
browsers::firefox.version#8
```

Comment: I cannot split with AND because I might have another operator OR for example